# How to automate the process of generating daily report from firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For example, to automate the process of producing a daily report for selected events and the duration of time that unique users spend on some specific event. And it is even better if I can customize the reporting information and have it generated in excel sheet automatically. Any suggestions or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is very broad; we don't know your platform, what kind of reporting you need, your Firebase structure etc. Also, firebase database doesn't have a direct export to excel option. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for you advice Jay. Since I just started using Firebase, I couldn't really tell my specific requirements at that moment. So I was really just looking for some approaches suggestions.

Comment: Understood. Please use the [Firebase Getting Started Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/guides/) and write some sample code to gain an understanding of how Firebase works. With your use case, you may also want to look at [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). Once you done that, you'll be in a much better spot to ask specific coding questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a Cloud Function to generate you excel report, for example by using excel4node (https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel4node)

And to call this Cloud Function regularly, you have to trigger it via http through a cron-job.

Have a look at:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CbE2PzvAMxA

Note: What works quite well too is to generate some PDFs via the Cloud Function, using pdfmake.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed gave me some insights on what approaches I could take to start.